# Tizen gear S2 keyboard error smiley

Tags: html, sdk, tizen, gears

Good evening,

I am currently working on making a Samsung Gear S2 APP using tizen sdk standalone (which works using HTML).

While working on this app we have an input (type number) to set a number, and all works fine by testing with the emulator, but when trying on a real device it seems the keyboard is showing Smilies when it should be showing just a conventional keyboard with numbers.

I write the html code that is not working properly:

```
<div id="unit-1">
    <input class="conversion-box" id="unit1" name="unit1" type="number" placeholder="0" maxlength="9"/>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me with this error? Many thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't faced this kind of issue.  Could you give the sample code?

Comment: Sure. I have edited the post with the code

Comment: I tested your code. I am not able to reproduce this on gear s2, If possible please upload the .wgt file and share the link.